# Making a Function Produce Different Values in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a web development course, and I currently need to implement a script into my webpage using JavaScript. I found a script I would like to use here:

http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Automatically-Changing-Slide-Show-Script.phtml

Basically, it changes the images automatically.

```
<head>
<script>

/*
JavaScript Image slideshow:
By Website Abstraction (www.wsabstract.com)
and Java-scripts.net (www.java-scripts.net)
*/

var slideimages=new Array()
var slidelinks=new Array()

function slideShowImages(){
  for (i=0;i<slideShowImages.arguments.length;i++){
    slideImages[i]=new Image();
    slideImages[i].src=slideShowImages.arguments[i];
  }
}

function goToShow(whichLink){
  if (!window.winslide||winslide.closed){
    winslide=window.open(slideLinks[whichLink])
  }else{
    winslide.location=slideLinks[whichLink]
    winslide.focus()
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- For reference, my actual code is 
    <a href="stagingandevents.html"/>
      <img src="pics/main/stagingandevents.jpg" alt="Staging and Events"
       name = "slide" width="300px" height="312"/>
    </a>
 -->

 <!-- Basically, I want two of the following image rotatations, but each
  link with different images. -->
 <a href="javascript:gotoshow()"><img src="img1.gif" name="slide"> 
 </a>

<script>
//configure the paths of the images, plus corresponding target links
slideshowimages("img1.gif", "img2.gif", "img3.gif")

//configure the speed of the slideshow, in miliseconds
var slideshowspeed=2000
var whichlink=0
var whichimage=0

function slideIt(){
  if (!document.images){
    return
   }
document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
whichlink=whichimage

  if (whichImage<slideImages.length-1) {
    whichImage++;
  } else {
      whichImage=0;
     } setTimeout("slideIt()",slideShowSpeed);

  }
  slideIt();
</script>
</body>
```

The code provided in the link is very old and deprecated, so I updated it a little. The slideShowImages() function is where the desired images are stored, but I don't know how to go about changing those values for each link!

I have tried several different things to get each link to have its own set of rotating images. As I am new to Javascript and HTML also, I really do not know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

The code to change the images and links is here

```
slideshowimages("img1.gif", "img2.gif", "img3.gif")
slideshowlinks("http://wsabstract.com", "http://dynamicdrive.com", "http://java-scripts.net")
```

You just need to insert your own pictures and links for those pictures.

```
slideshowimages("images/myFirstImage.gif", "images/mySecondImage.gif", "images/myThirdImage.gif")
slideshowlinks("http://myfirstimagelink.com", "http://mysecondimagelink.com", "http://mythirdimagelink.net")
```

Comment: I understand how to set the images in slideshowimages("img1.gif", "img2.gif", "img3.gif"), what I do not know how to do is make it so my first link has those 3 images, and my second link has another set like slideshowimages("img4.gif", "img5.gif", "img6.gif")

Comment: The first position in each function relate to each other so just duplicate the URL 3 times in slideshowlinks() for img1, 2 and 3 and then again for 4, 5 and 6.